# Scrolling in UITableView embedded in UITableviewCell (ios7)

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have `UITableView` added as subview of `UITableviewCell`.
In iOS 6 when I scroll internal `tableView` and reach to the end of it main table view becomes scrolling.
In iOS 7 it doesn't work anymore. If I am scrolling in internal table view it doesn't deliver this scroll event to parent tableView.

Does anyone know how to simply fix it, without manual transferring event from internal tableview to parent?

Additional info:
I find possible reason of [problem](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646). But how to fix this problem.

Comment: Why would you do this? Adding TableView in TableViewCell is not recommended.

Comment: I need to display content that doesn't fit into cell size.

Comment: Have you tried a UICollectionView instead of a UITableView?

Comment: I have to support iOS 5. :)

Comment: @FaisalAli, why is not recommended ? Do you have any Apple doc that says that ?

Comment: Cell height is configurable. You should dynamically calculate height and return it in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and add your custom view as subview to your cell, if you really want your content to fit in one cell. Whatever you plan to do in the inner table can simple be transfered to the outter table. In case you want to make a clear separation of the content, you should use sections.

Comment: I know all of this, but I have to do as I describe it. I don't look for alternative I only need to fix this issue on iOS7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found a solution.

According to tip from @FaisalAli I implement delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)                         gestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass: [UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        if ([((UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer) velocityInView: self].y > 0)
        {
            // Up
            if (self.contentOffset.y <= 0)
            {
                self.bounces = NO;
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Down
            if (self.contentOffset.y + self.height >= self.contentSize.height)
            {
                self.bounces = NO;
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    self.bounces = YES;

    return NO;
}
```

And it helped.

Comment: In case someone didn't got it: 
The tableview instance that you embed must implement shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer. You can copy the code from above for calculating return value or you can just return !(self.contentOffset.y > 0). Hope that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is wise solution regarding ease of use for user. You should use [Master-Detail Strategy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html).

Set `UINavigationController` as rootViewController, then push your Master `TableViewController`, on selection of each cell you can push new `TableViewController` having detailed data of selected Cell Item.

**Edit**

If you really want to add TableView inside a TableViewCell then, please follow [link 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) and [link 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2).

Comment: Even though you are absolutely right about MVC conformity, nested `UITableView`s is an acceptable design pattern. It does increase the coder's overhead of memory and performance optimization, but if done right, yields some very good results.

Comment: Handling TableView's delegate and datasource in TableViewCell is neither piece of cake ... :) I think using my strategy will reduce complexity.

Comment: @abagmut I have edited my answer according to your requirement. Review it if it helps.

Comment: you are right about complexity, but a good app is one that provides the user with the best user experience, irrespective of how hard it was for the coder to make.

Comment: @FaisalAli I've viewed link you gave and don't found anything useful according to my problem (when this articles has been written there weren't ios 7).
To make clear, on ios6 all work perfect, problems appear only on ios7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198550/uiscrollview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-horizontal-scrolling try this

Comment: Thanks, it helped. 

But now when I scroll internal tableview, external tableview became scrolling as well and it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: I work around to enable scrolling external table only after reaching the end of internal tableview by I've faced with another problem. At the end of internal tableview scroll I get: contentOffset.y=54.000000, tableView.height=269.000000, contentSize.height=323.123047 Why I get additional *.123047 to contentSize?

Comment: I found the reason of this problem. It's due to incorrect calculating table view content size when I return float value from tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:. When I cast return value to int table calculates its content size correctly.